# Creating plain API which accepts files

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building an API which accepts file and validates it, sends json response (not storing the file in db, so no need of model). I have created a class based view, in post function, `request.FILES` or `request.POST` doesn’t contain the file… If I make a form class, it will work. But, I don’t want any UI, it should be a simple API. Anyone knows how to do it?

```
class ValidateView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.FILES
        if not file:
            return JsonResponse({"status_code": "400", "message": "a file is required", "status_response": "Bad Request"})
        return JsonResponse({"status_code": "200", "message": "data validated", "status_response": "Success"})

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ValidateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I used `djangorestframework` and come up with this

```
class ValidateView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        if is_csv_valid(file_obj):
            return Response(status=200, data={"message": "valid file"})
        else:
            return Response(status=400, data={"message": "not valid"})
```

But, here the problem is I must build a url like this

```
re_path("validate/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$", ValidateView.as_view(), name="api-validate")
```

If I exclude `filename` in url, it throws an error. Also, `file_obj` contains some extra lines along with original data like this.

```
[b'----------------------------634867545113999762020341\r\n', b'Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="kafka_word_count_input.txt"\r\n', b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n', 'original_data']
```

Someone help!!!

Comment: your API class seems fine. The problem may lie in the API calling procedure. You should've sent data as **`form-data`**, not as JSON

Comment: I am sending request from `postman` with `form-data` option selected and attached a file

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I cannot access file object in `request.FILES` or in `request.POST` , I don't see that in request object...

Comment: I copy pasted your DRF view and run. It's working as expected.

Comment: Yup, it's working but the problem is if you run `file_obj.readlines()` and `print` it, what are you getting??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184851/discussion-between-lokesh-s-and-jpg).

Answer (score 0):

you can create the serializer

```
class FileSerializer(serializer.Serializers):
    file = serializer.FileFiled()

    def validate_file(self, value):
        # write  logic to validate
       if not is_csv_valid(value):
          raise serializer.ValidationError("wrong file")
       else:
         return value

 class ValidateView(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
          return Response(status=200, data={"message": "valid file"})
```

now send the reuqest in form data

Comment: can you tell me without using DRF

Comment: do you want with django  only?

Comment: hey, I posted the answer... I figured it out... thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... The problem is I am not sending key `file` from `postman`. This I figured it out, when using `curl`... wowww, command line tools rocks...

also, I need to use `request.FILES['file']` to access file and do my stuff...